# Moving Azure SQL to another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am planning to move my Azure SQL server and one database contained within it to another subscription, within the same tenant.

I did find a documentation online, which, surprisingly was 9 years old.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/moving-sql-azure-servers-between-subscriptions/

It doesn't tell what will be copied and what will not be copied.
Does anyone know this, has anybody recently tried this move.
Will the be schema be copied, but not the data in the database or is it not going to copy anything at all?

Any information on this is much appreciated.

Edit :
I know about the "Move" button in the azure portal.
Just want to know whether my data will also be moved.
Been reading articles which say that i would lose the data.

Davis.

Comment: Can you share the articles that say you will lose the data?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-migrate-the-SQL-data-between-two-subscriptions-in-Azure-Portal

Comment: That seems to me to be addressing the option to move a copy while keeping the original.  This article on Microsoft docs descibes that a move is OK and mentions that the actual resource doesn;t physically move https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259

Answer (score 1):

It is as easy as going to the database in the portal and clicking on the Change Subscription link as highlighted in the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I want to know, is whether my data will also be copied?

Comment: Yes - the entire database changes subscription.  As the original article also mentioned all that happens is that the relationship to the subscription changes and it is likely that the database itself does not even move.  Can you point me to articles that say you will lose the data?

Comment: Here's the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftsql